# Step motor movement

Tags: microcontroller, stepper-motor

I have found code for running a step motor ( https://os.mbed.com/users/XtaticO/code/sMotor/file/4b3b9e047ce3/sMotor.cpp/ ), however I am not sure if it is correct:

```
void sMotor:anticlockwise() { //rotate the motor 1 step anticlockwise
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        switch (i) { // activate the ports A0, A2, A3, A3 in a binary sequence for steps
        case 0: {
            _A0=0;
            _A1=0;
            _A2=0;
            _A3=1;
        }
        break;
        case 1: {
            _A0=0;
            _A1=0;
            _A2=1;
            _A3=1;
        }
        break;
        case 2: {
            _A0=0;
            _A1=0;
            _A2=1;
            _A3=0;
        }
        break;
        case 3: {
            _A0=0;
            _A1=1;
            _A2=1;
            _A3=0;
        }
        break;
        case 4: {
            _A0=0;
            _A1=1;
            _A2=0;
            _A3=0;
        }
        break;
        case 5: {
            _A0=1;
            _A1=1;
            _A2=0;
            _A3=0;
        }
        break;
        case 6: {
            _A0=1;
            _A1=0;
            _A2=0;
            _A3=0;
        }
        break;
        case 7: {
            _A0=1;
            _A1=0;
            _A2=0;
            _A3=1;
        }
        break;
    }


    wait_us(motorSpeed); // wait time defines the speed 
    }
}
```

The rest of the class works with this implementation, am I right in assuming that calling this function will move the motor 8 steps, and not one, or is there something I do not understand.

Comment: It appears to move 8 half-steps.

Comment: Top understand what's going on you need a drawing of the motor wires and how the bits drive those wires (probably via an H- bridge),  and what those wires go to inside the motor (i.e four electro-magnet coils). The bit sequence energizes those coils in an order that generates a rotation.

Comment: `not sure if it is correct` .... correct for what? .... it would totally not work on my arduino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many explanations on the web for this problem with full details .

This dual coil 4 wire configuration uses bipolar current in 4 phases for 4 steps or 8 half steps or 16 quarter steps and more . Speed and torque are tradeoffs for higher resolution with fractional current steps.
[image]

Here you can convert the state changes in current to binary logic to mean bipolar current shown here with 8 half-steps that can repeat repeated for the number of rotor+stator poles per rev. x4.

Full steps have the greatest torque.

Comment: Does this mean these 8 "microsteps" are equal to one full step?

Comment: No it means there are 4 full. steps or, phases with full bipolar current on both outputs. Half steps use half current in alternate steps of each coil to make 8 steps while micro stepping reduces the current even smaller steps to make more sinusoidal but compromises RMS current per cycle thru all microsteps